# rhel + upgrade individual rpm's from rhel 7.1 to rhel 7.7 or batch upgrade of rpms

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, kernel, rpm

We have rhel 7.1 version server , with local repositories of rhel 7.1 ( with rpms’ from rhel 7.1 )

We want to replace the local repository with rpm’s of rhel 7.7

so we intend to Remove the local repo of 7.1 as

```
rm -rf /var/RHEL7.1
```

and create new repo for 7.7 as

```
mkdir /var/RHEL7.7
```

and push to `/var/RHEL7.7/Packages` all rpm’s that related to rhel 7.7

and replace the repo conf as

Example

```
/etc/yum.repo.d/rhel7.1.repo
```

To

```
/etc/yum.repo.d/rhel7.7.repo
```

So every `yum install`or `yum update`  , will point to the repository of rpms from rhel 7.7 ( `/etc/yum.repo.d/rhel7.7` )

We not sure if we can upgrade each rpm from rhel 7.1 to rhel 7.7 , so I want to ask the forum here , if this is possible and update of every rpm from rhel 7.1 to 7.7 can be done without problem

so dose upgrade of individual rpm's from rhel 7.1 to rhel 7.6 or batch of rpm cam be risk or with conflict?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a `yum update` and every package will be updated to the latest version. Minor versions of the distribution is automatic updated in RHEL

Comment: yum update is just if want to perform rhel upgrade to 7.7 , what I am asking after we set the repo to 7.7 version if this is safety to do yum upgrade to one individual rpm or batch of rpm of XX rpm's ?

Comment: I just return about my quation again , maybe it wa not clear , when I replace the local repo from rhel 7.1 to rhel 7.7 maybe some rpm's from rhel 7.7 will be in conflicts because the upgrade from rhel 7.1 to rhel 7.7 , but I not sure about this  , dose all rpme from 7.7 are backward compatibility ? to rhel .1?

Comment: every dependency are satisfied when an update occur. If you update just one package from an 7.7 version and there is a package from 7.6 version than the Yum will install the needed packages automatically

Comment: so just to be sure do you say that moving to rhel 7.7 repo will not cause any conflicts with yum update indevdual or not?

Comment: it won't cause any conflict as long as you don't have any third-party packages installed manually or locally compiled. If all your packages was installed with official RH repository, all dependencies are validated before each installation

Comment: The rest of us did these updates years ago. Of course it's safe.

Comment: can you give advice when this upgrade  isnt safe for example lets say we want upgrade from 7.1 to 8.x , so in that case its also safe ?

Comment: A major version change like from 7 to 8 is a much bigger leap, and cannot be done with only a `yum update`.  Read the documentation about how to plan and execute such an upgrade.

Comment: so you agree with @Michael Hampton about no issue from rhel 7.1 to rhel 7.7 ?